# How do I map recordset to an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to return an array. I read a recordset from SQL and get data:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| start_type | field_name | start_text |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | Field1     | some text. |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | Field2     | some more  |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | Field3     | still more |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to return this as an array, I try (in a function with  `Promise<StartText>`):

```
var results: Array<StartText>=[];
results=result.recordset;
return results;
```

with StartText:

```
    export class StartText {
  constructor(
    public startTextId: number,
    public fieldName: string,
    public startText: string
  ) {}

  static from(row: {
    start_text_id: number;
    field_name: string;
    start_text: string;
  }): StartText {
    return new StartText(
      row.start_text_id,
      row.field_name,
      row.start_text
    );
  }

  static toList(result: { recordset: any[] }): StartText[] {
    const StartTexts: StartText[] = [];
    result.recordset.forEach((element: any) => {
      StartTexts.push(StartText.from(element));
    });
    return StartTexts;
  }
}
```

but this says:

```
'StartText[]' is missing the following properties from type 'StartText': startTextId, fieldName, startText.
```

So how do I return the recordset (actually ideally I would like to return a single value for start_type and a dictionary of  field_name: start_text pairs but first things first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the promise to: `Promise <Array<StartText>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Typescript is that you don't need classes for everything because you can assign types and interfaces to plain objects instead.  The `from` method of your `StartText` class doesn't really to anything.  The `row` argument [is already](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQGMA2BDAzlpBlBDRAFUmQG9QlUYA7LBOAVxQXgAorqkomAjNAEsUSBkQSkICAJIATAFxJaTALZ8wcADRdqvAcKQAzQWDSyAchhVhFDOINoBzbSG49%20QkWJJlbjB45cAJRI5AC%20oFxiCAaGcDAq7PEA7oqUrtzeCAD6CGTZggpKqupwANw6RiZm2bRWNqL%20ThUZ1Fm5vo32zVxhQYoE4pIUlXBgCExwtEpgyfiEPlKcrdwpAHTteVIFsi5u1OvGprK19Xv765tklUEt1BEgUYQxImwAMoIMSWBYTGgIaSQYxQ8FkWHGigwtAAngBtAC6SD6AwWEjICNClRB9GQg0WCCwKKG6MRAF4kAi7qsfn8EGtgaDwXTDPAAKIYFAAC3Y7FMYGstABSCh0JCpIAfJiVtQ8WipFg1rwsNzZcM1nEEry0PywIKgrdKn0qQdxpNpqqyFgqQ8HqBsQwgRg5uT0m4ssM5IoAAznahHMyWayKABEADFqrIAIzB32NYlSEPB0C2kD25BYBJgUNMWgicnsGB8ABWYFYRPxYsl4UiIAA9LWlDBkFCkBp4nAAITUdQoDBMcGOuYqDAILk-JAITlgJAOPKGDnTmCGebxhCgDPWbO5pJO25AA) a `StartText`!  You are changing the property names to camelCase but that's it.

I would recommend against using a class here.  Just define an interface for the row:

```
interface StartText {
    start_text_id: number;
    field_name: string;
    start_text: string;
}
```

Your `constructor`, `from`, and `toList` all become unnecessary.  Your SQL data looks like this:

```
interface SqlResult {
    recordset: StartText[];
}
```

---

> actually ideally I would like to return a single value for start_type and a dictionary of field_name: start_text pairs but first things first

I always start by defining the types.  All of the rows have the same `start_type`?  And we want to convert them into a dictionary?  Or are there multiple values of `start_type` and we want to group them into a dictionary of dictionaries?  Here is the "dictionary of dictionaries" approach.  You could extract a single dictionary from that as needed.

```
type FormattedData = Record<string, Record<string, string>>

const formatSql = (sql: SqlResult): FormattedData => {
```

If that's the signature that you want then here's the code to do it:

```
const formatSql = (sql: SqlResult): FormattedData => {
    // an empty object is assignable to the type, but we need to set the type for the initial value
    const initial: FormattedData = {};
    return sql.recordset.reduce((formatted, row) => {
        return {
            ...formatted, // copy all other id objects
            [row.start_text_id]: { // replace this id object
                ...formatted[row.start_text_id], // copy all other properties
                [row.field_name]: row.start_text // add this property
            }
        }
    }, initial);
}
```

This converts to an object of the form:

```
{
  "0": {
    "Field1": "some text",
    "Field2": "some more",
    "Field3": "still more"
  }
}
```

Test it out! [Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjlMAVCAPMZAbwFgAoZS5AZwywH1ID7gATALmRAFcBbAI2gBuclWQxgEADat6IOLwidaUUAHMRFKrUxhG%20MMrCqQG8gF9y5UJFiIUqAI5SAShGrcphUlspQICAD2UKzUEIZodDgGANoAupqWZORgAJ4ADigAYsG8cGCQrAAi%20XDIALzIbkEhADw8AtAANFUBway1KuotXaYAfH1WZEEgtOK5%20U5SFcgAFNTOnFNuHl4AlJw5UHkFEMWlFX3EolQA9KfIcCDIELzpaciB-ABWAYTA1JfU1MBq8vxSFBgQLIMAACyBGQgLX43EIAHcUCAIHtQSCwoRwZDMuMoKCIchQMAwMA4NMAG5k7gQE6UEZjIkksmbCa7fYYGZEcyaMT%20MDcKDXBZSAB0-hqoXCYr23CQs1mMFZhRaUEC8LWh2OvjEyD5AuuPh1RuQItNiu2%20WVyHOyCC6VSlyk00CWLxbEeLze1FpxsoMVV8JFOgYTD0bDinCI1ou-nSUns%20I%20hNYHteCDAPt9YlNIvNO0K-rVQai%20mY4ZaNrtDrJztdyHSqsyWEk3u1WaohcDEmksnkigjuqLwb0oejl1YKfBSYbgSbaUzxqSvqXVHMLUZpKka0SQ3phGFJQwS2cK08hEqhqo4vaGM4MQXlEv7eHpbDHGQAAYmg%20dd2ZHIFCUZAACIskkGQAEZgO-NtjRfUNOGA6hAkUUEDGgn81y1dtKHggwWHfL8fzEP9e0AxCwJ7AAmDDYKNPCCEQ5DUN4YIIFo5cWifLMGLfTgiLo39wLIxQKOEgBmDicN4piSSdZBWP8YDMJ9OILE0ch6UCQERSkQI1AVVkpnmZxDzgNZtyAA)